# Remotely control desktop without downloading anything? How does join.me do it?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, webrtc

How does join.me allow attendees to control someone else's desktop without requiring a download on their part? Unless we're mistaken, it seems like only the organizer is required to download anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't specifically know how join.me does their desktop sharing, but there are JavaScript-only solutions for the client, like http://kanaka.github.com/noVNC/, so that all you'd need is  for the organizer to have a VNC client installed. SmartCode has a version of a VNC ActiveX control that almost certainly violates the VNC GPL ([here](http://www.s-code.com/products/serverx/)), but it might be something you'd want to look into for the organizer-side.